# Unable to find a method in CFC

Tags: jquery, web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Basically I', going through a code and encountered the following ajax call using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
url: '<cfoutput>#rootUrl#/#SessionPath#</cfoutput>/cfc/xyz.cfc?
method=AddNewBatch&returnformat=json&queryformat=column&_cf_nodebug=true&_cf_nocache=true',
```

1) I have gone through the `xyz.cfc` many times and unable to find any method with name, `AddNewBatch`. Am I doing something wrong? Please clarify.

2) Also, could you explain what the returnformat in the URL is doing? Or please let me know if there's any documentation available for the type of returnformat mentioned in above url, I'll go through that.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still confused with my question #1.For second question,I understand that it's JSON format but wondering what's `queryformat=column&_cf_nodebug=true&_cf_nocache=true` all about?

Comment: Okay, Thanks !! I'll figure that out.

Comment: Tan, once again... if you're asking code questions, you need to provide the code! Does xyz.cfc extend another CFC? Does it have an `onMissingMethod()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others are alluding to it already, but it's possible that your xyz.cfc extends another CFC that does have the method AddNewBatch().  Look at the top of the xyz.cfc code and see if the component line has an "extends" attribute. If so, find that CFC and you may find your method.

If you're not familiar, one CFC can "extend" another, meaning that it includes all of its functions AND the functions of the extended CFC.  This is an object oriented concept.

Answer (score 0):

1) You are accessing this method remotely. Make sure that you have access="remote" in the function AddNewBatch definition in your xyz.cfc

```
<cfcomponent displayname="I am Xy Y Z" output="false">

    <cffunction name="AddNewBatch" access="remote" output="false" returnformat="JSON">
        <!--- do something here --->
        <cfset var somestruct={structkey1=1,structkey2=2}>
        <cfreturn somestruct />
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

2)  "returnformat" is parameter that you are passing to this method. Never tried this approach, but when I set returnFormat in function definition, I am sure that this function will always returns JSON "stringified" back, no mather if I returned query or any other object. See the example.

Check out the last answer here, It might give you some ideas. [How should I send variables to a coldfusion action page with ajax post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790876/how-should-i-send-variables-to-a-coldfusion-action-page-with-ajax-post/18797298#18797298)